# How to Send/Receive Information Typed in on my Websites booknow.html Page to email or other method

Tags: php, html, email

I have built an html page for the Book Now page of my residential house painting website; but, have been unable to figure out how I can receive the information that a visitor to my site types into that page. When I built the page I researched something regarding php; however, the information did not elaborate on what I needed to do to have the information sent/received to either my email or other method of receiving it.  I think email would be best; but, am not sure if I need to set up a database or what needs to be done to get the info.

If someone could point me in the right direction of some information regarding this or has an easy method of doing this, your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-35390079-2">
    </script>
    <script>
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
            gtag('js', new Date());
            gtag('config', 'UA-35390079-2');
    </script>
    <script language="php"> </script>
    <title>
            Grade A Painters | Resdidential House Painting
    </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
           .error {color: #FF0000;}
           * {box-sizing: border-box;}
           /* Style inputs */
           input[type=text], select, textarea { width: 100%;padding: 12px; border: 1px solid #ccc; margin-top: 6px; margin-bottom: 16px; resize: vertical;}
           input[type=submit] {background-color: #4CAF50; color: white; padding: 12px 20px; border: none; cursor: pointer;}
           input[type=submit]:hover {background-color: #45a049;}
           /* Style the container/contact section */
           .container {border-radius: 5px; background-color: #f2f2f2; padding: 10px;}
           /* Create two columns that float next to eachother */
           .column {float: left; width: 50%; margin-top: 6px; padding: 20px;}
           /* Clear floats after the columns */
           .row:after {content: ""; display: table; clear: both;}
           /* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 600px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
           @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {.column, input[type=submit] {width: 100%; margin-top: 0;}}
           h3 {text-align : center; font-size : 36px; color: #3F729B;}
           h2 {color: #3F729B;}
            h4 {font-size: 16px; color:darkblue; font-family:Helvetica;}
           h1 {text-align : center; font-size: 48px; color:#ED1C24;font-family:Helvetica;}
           h5 {text-align : center; color : #ED1C24;}
           img {border-radius: 16px;}
           .b {font-style: italic; text-align: center;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div style="text-align:center">
      <h2>Grade A Painters Estimate Contact Form</h2>
      <br><br>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <a href="index.html">
          <img src="OldLogo.jpg" style="width:100%" alt="Company Logo">
        </a>
        <br><br>
        <h3>What are our clients saying about us?</h3>
        <br>
        <p class="b">Excellent job, professional, clean, caring and reasonably priced.  I would not hesitate to
                          recommend this company. - Alison Koch</p>
        <br>
        <p class="b">Very high quality work, amazing finish and crisp lines. Left the area clean and good
                          housekeeping. No regrets from choosing Grade A Painters! - Trever Crowe</p>
        <br>
        <p class="b">Chris at Grade A painters painted my whole house on the inside and did some outside work as
                          well. My house was renovated so they painted new drywall. After we moved in Chris offered to
                          come back and touch up any walls that may have had dings from the moving. He kept his word!
                          Since then I have referred him to many clients, friends and family who were are all as equally
                          impressed. - Leanne Woodward</p>
        <br>
        <p class="b">Absolutely satisfied amazing job! - Marcus Anthony Ray</p>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <h2>What Can We Paint For You?</h2>
        <p><span class="error">* required field</span></p>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);">
          <br>
          Type of Job:
          <input type="radio" name="jobtype" value="interior">Inside My Home
          <input type="radio" name="jobtype" value="exterior">Exterior
          <input type="radio" name="jobtype" value="Commercial">Commercial
          <span class="error">* <?php echo $jobtypeErr;?></span>
          <br><br>
          Job Details: <textarea name="jobdetails" input id="input1" type="text" rows="5" cols="40"
          placeholder="Examples: 3 bdrm, drywall repairs ect."></textarea>
          <br><br>
          <h2>Your Contact Information</h2>
          <br><br>
          First Name: <span class="error">* <?php echo $firstnameErr;?></span>
          <input type="text" name="firstname">
          <br><br>
          Last Name: <span class="error">* <?php echo $lastnameErr;?></span>
          <input type="text" name="lastname">
          <br><br>
          Phone: <span class="error">* <?php echo $phoneErr;?></span>
          <input type="tel" name="phone">
          <br><br>
          E-mail: <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
          <input type="text" name="email">
          <br><br>
          <h2>Service Address</h2>
          <br><br>
          Address: <span class="error">* <?php echo $addressErr;?></span>
          <input type="text" name="address">
          <br><br>
          City: <span class="error">* <?php echo $cityErr;?></span>
          <input type="text" name="city">
          <br><br>
          Site Details: <textarea name="sitedetails" input id="input2" type="text" rows="5" cols="40"
          placeholder="Examples: buzzer number, parking ect."></textarea>
          <br><br>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="bg-dark">
            <h1>CALL US TODAY!</h1>
            <h3><a href="tel:16047269705">604-726-9705</a></h3>
            <h5> Monday - Friday 8am - 9pm Pacific</h5>
            <h5> Saturday 9am - 9pm Pacific</h5>
            <h5> Sunday 10am - 6pm Pacific</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-copyright bg-info text-center py-3">© 2020 Copyright:
          <a href="https://gradeapainters.com" class="text-danger">GradeAPainters.com</a>
      </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: PHP's built in mail function requires that the host has a working email server configuration. There are third-party PHP libraries that can enable this kind of capability for use with external email servers such as, for example, gmail.

Comment: Ok, so do I need to include some information within my html code or should I contact one of these third-party libraries and have them apply their service to my site?

Comment: It'll be something added to your PHP and it's more of a do-it-yourself kind of thing.